# Linux 64 bit to AWS ARM architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, arm

Is there any option of transferring existing AWS 64-bit Linux image to the new ARM architecture?
What is the best approach for migration in such a case? I made an image of an instance, but unable to launch the instance due to architecture mismatch.
Not sure everything must be rebuilt from scratch or there is a way of somehow making the image compatible.

Comment: In general everything that is native will need to be recompiled.  What is your development environment?  Precompiled packages should exist for all of the "standard" things such as databases.

Comment: You may pay attention to the difference between the arch that current AWS 64-bit Linux image supports and the new Armv8.x arch.